# plist in Xcode creation

Tags: iphone, xcode, plist

When I am creating a simple application for plist shown in below link:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html

When I am debugging it.. I am getting path of my plist file. But when I am using the following statement

```
// Build the array from the plist  
NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

I don't get any value in array2... What could be the problem?

Comment: i have kept this code in   - (void) viewDidLoad{}

Comment: How do you getting the path? How do you create the plist? Do you try to red it from main bundle or from the apps documents directory?

Comment: -(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DrinkArray" ofType:@"plist"];
   NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
   for(NSString *str in array2)
   {
       NSLog(@"--%@",str);
   }
}

Comment: Where is your plist file man?

Comment: i have plist file in my Supported Files group. It contains the Root element as Array and 3 Strings element in Root array

Comment: Do an NSLog on your array. NSLog(@"Array:%@",[array2 description]);

Comment: yes i logged it.. but i am getting null value in array2.. But I have also observed with other application that when i take only 1 string in plist and i m doing same process but instead of using NSMutableArray.. i m using NSString... then i am able to get that string in NSLog...?? so what could be the problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the final solution that i got for plist....

When u are creating your plist file with first element as Array.. then its XML Contents will be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Root</key>
    <array>
        <string>Firecracker</string>
        <string>Lemon Drop</string>
        <string>Mojito</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here you are having unnecessary  tag  instead of which we should have  as your root element must be Array... because u are taking in NSMutableArray object...

so your plist file must be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <string>Firecracker</string>
        <string>Lemon Drop</string>
        <string>Mojito</string>
    </array>
</plist>
```

i have checked that its working fine....

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be

1. The file doesn't exist at specified path, you get `nil` in `array2`.
2. The file exists but it cannot be read correctly, due to some format corruption, and you get `nil` in `array2` too.
3. The file exists and its format is correct, but there are no values in, you get an empty array.

When using `NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DrinkArray" ofType:@"plist"];`, it assumes you have a correctly formed plist file named "DrinkArray" ('DrinkArray.plist'), inside your app bundle. Make sure your file is also copied into the app bundle (check this in Xcode, click on your project, then Build phases, your file should appear in the 'Copy Bundle Ressources').

I guess you get `nil`as the path to the file, and therefore in `array2`. Try to log your path string to check it.

Comment: I have checked the 'Copy Bundle Resources' and it shows me the DrinkArray.plist file. Also my project in Xcode shows me that file in Supported Files group. Still i am getting null value in array2...

Comment: ok just log your path to the file using `NSLog(@"%@", path);` and tell us what it prints

Comment: /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator 4.3/Applications/<Some Values>/plistDemo.app/DrinkArray.plist
  
This is shown in path when i keep nslog

Comment: so if the file really exists really at this path (what you can easily check) and it is well formed (like the picture shown on the page linked), there shoudln't be any problem

Comment: please post back, this issue is really interesting

Comment: Here is the steps that i followed : 1. created NSMutableArray *drinks and property in .h file.   2. then i have synthesize property, then i added the code in viewDidLoad. and then i have written self.drinks = tmparray.   Is there any mistake in this steps.?? .. m still not able to get data from plist  file...

Comment: so probably, either you do not retain the property, or tmparray is empty. try `NSLog(@"%@", tmparray);` just before `self.drinks = tmparray;`

Comment: i kept nslog before self.drinks = tmparray; but still null value is shown

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like this:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Root"];

    // Show the string values  
    for (NSString *str in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"--%@", str);
    }
```

If that helped, please, drop a line. :)

Cheers,
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

In xcode 5 > make sure the file is in your compile sources area. [image]