# Issue loading plist into NSArray on ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to load a simple plist file in XCode 4 for an iPad application. The goal being that it will be loaded into the table portion of a split-view.

My project structure and plist look as follows:

[image]

I then declare an array in the interface of the RootViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *sites;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;

@end
```

I then, on viewDidLoad, attempt to load in the plist:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    //NSLog(bundle);
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"StoredSites" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(path);

    sites = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%d", [sites count]);

}
```

The NSLog statements first return what appears to be the valid path, but upon try to load the NSArray with the contents of the file, it comes back with a count of 0:

[image]

I checked in the build phases to see if the file reference appears, and it seems to be ok:

[image]

I know this must be a simple problem, but for some reason I'm not seeing what's missing!

I appreciate the help -

Comment: some what similar issue is discussed in my previous post please [go through the link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693333/plist-in-xcode-creation-problem

Comment: That was my EXACT issue, the root node was wrapped in a dictionary - thanks for the link! I upvoted all of your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the plist XML was wrapped in a dictionary rather than just being a simple array of arrays -

DShah covers it here: [plist in xcode creation problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693333/plist-in-xcode-creation-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to using an `NSDictionary`, as that is what the sample code given [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the method `pathForResource:ofType:` uses.

I'm not entirely sure why it isn't working with an `NSArray`, but maybe the `plist` isn't formatted entirely correctly? The [documentation for NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) says that `initWithContentsOfFile:` takes in as a parameter quote:

> The path to a file containing a string representation of an array
>   produced by the writeToFile:atomically: method.

Again, I'm not really sure. Hope that Helps!