# how to properly retain data read from plist?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, plist

I am stuck debugging a NSInvalidArgumentException. My latest suspicion is that I didn't retain the data read from plist properly so that it's occupied by some other object while I access it.

My plist structure is very complicated, it has 8 levels of arrays/dictionaries. I think I lost the memory when I try to access the lowest object.

I wonder if I have to retain every data element when I read the plist file or is it sufficient to just retain the top level object?

This is how I read:

```
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSError *error = [[[NSError alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray *temp = (NSArray *)[[NSPropertyListSerialization
                            propertyListWithData:plistXML 
                            options:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves
                            format:nil 
                            error:&error] retain];
self.dataPackage = [temp objectAtIndex:0];
```

`dataPackage` is declared as:

```
@interface rootViewController:UIViewController{
  NSDictionary *dataPackage;
}
@property (retain) NSDictionary *dataPackage;
```

and synthesized:

```
@synthesize dataPackage;
```

Am I doing it right?

Thanks

Leo

Comment: Please provide more details on what exception you got and what it said?  Invalid argument?  Which one? on which line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed 3 things:

- You don't need to create an NSError object! NSPropertyListSerialization will return an error object if something fails. Just init with:  `NSError *error = nil;`
- You don't have to retain the (autoreleasing) temp-array, you obviously don't need the whole array  after fetching the object at index 0.
- `[temp objectAtIndex:0]` will crash when the array is empty!

Be sure to release the property var in dealloc with `self.dataPackage = nil`. Then everything is safe from memory management perspective.

Comment: thanks for the tips.  will {self.dataPackage = nil}  release and set to nil in just one call?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the structure of Plist in TextEdit.... For more go through my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693333/plist-in-xcode-creation-problem/6716122#6716122)  If you are using Xcode 4 then this might be the reason. The structure might got changed in xcode 4.